# I'm using React Native Expo & I'm facing this error [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAvailableCameraDevices' of null]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, camera, expo

After I have installed react-native-vision-camera using expo, I can not open the camera.

Here is my code:

```
const ScanProduct =({navigation})=>{

    // Camera
    const devices = useCameraDevices('wide-angle-camera')
    const device = devices.back

    React.useEffect(()=>{
      requestCameraPermission
  },[])

    // Handler
    const requestCameraPermission = React.useCallback(async ()=>{
        const permission = await Camera.requestCameraPermission();
        

        if(permission === 'denied') await Linking.openSettings()
    },[])


    function renderCamera(){
      
        if(device == null){
          return(
            <View
               style={{
                flex:1,
               }}
            />
          )

        } else{
          return(
            <View
              style={{
                flex:1
              }}
            >

              <Camera
                style={{flex:1}}
                device={device}
                isActive={true}
                enableZoomGesture
              
              />

            </View>
          )
        }
      
    }

    return(
        <View>

            {/*Camera*/}
            {renderCamera()}

        </View>
    )
}
```

Between I run the code on my iphone using Expo Go app and the app can run smoothly except the code camera above giving me this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAvailableCameraDevices' of null.`
Anyone can help me out is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you didn't call the requestCameraPermission properly in use effect, missed to add ()!?

```
requestCameraPermission();
```

Also, you do not need to use "else", as "if" already has the return statement.

```js
const ScanProduct = ({ navigation }) => {
  // Camera
  const devices = useCameraDevices("wide-angle-camera");
  const device = devices.back;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    requestCameraPermission();
  }, []);

  // Handler
  const requestCameraPermission = React.useCallback(async () => {
    const permission = await Camera.requestCameraPermission();

    if (permission === "denied") await Linking.openSettings();
  }, []);

  function renderCamera() {
    if (device == null) {
      return <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />;
    }

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Camera
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          device={device}
          isActive={true}
          enableZoomGesture
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      {/*Camera*/}
      {renderCamera()}
    </View>
  );
};
```

or I would rather

```js
const style = { flex: 1 }

const ScanProduct = ({ navigation }) => {
 // Permissions and useEffect...

  function RederCamera() {
    if (!device) return </>;

    return (          
      <Camera
        style={style}
        device={device}
        isActive={true}
        enableZoomGesture
      />          
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={style}>
      <RederCamera />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Also below should work without </>

```
if (!device) return
```

Or just

```js
  return (
    <View>
      {devive ? (
        <Camera style={style} device={device} isActive={true} enableZoomGesture />
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: Well, first of all, thank you so much for your answers, between I have followed and copied your answer to the editor but unfortunately still not working and got another error  ` TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestCameraPermission' of null]`

Answer (score 0):

This error seems like a build issue. After installing the npm package and add the plugin in you app.json

```
{
  "name": "my app",
  "plugins": [
    [
      "react-native-vision-camera",
      {
        "cameraPermissionText": "$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs access to your Camera.",

        // optionally, if you want to record audio:
        "enableMicrophonePermission": true,
        "microphonePermissionText": "$(PRODUCT_NAME) needs access to your Microphone."
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Then you need to rebuild your app by typing. *Don't forget to change the platform and profile attributes based on your need.*

```
eas build --platform ios --profile development
```

Comment: Hello, Caner, actually I have done that in app.js but may I know where to type eas build ... because I did typed in the editor terminal and I got this  ** The term 'eas' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program**

Comment: @BashamlanSalem you need to install eas-cli by entering npm install -g eas-cli

Comment: well, I have done it but still giving this error { TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestCameraPermission' of null] }. do you think because of my iphone 8 because I run Expo Go on iphone 8

Comment: After entering "eas build --platform ios --profile development", expo will give a link to download the app. Go to expo.dev > builds > last build > click download > unzip the folder > drag and drop the app into the simulator. I'm pretty sure it'll fix your problem.

Comment: I'm not using simulator but I'm using physically device iphone 8  which I installed Expo Go on in then I scan the app QR code of my app to run on my phone.